# Is a copy made when passing by 'implied'(?) reference in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

If I have a function that takes a reference to a map:

```
pair<int,int> myFunc(map<int,char> &myVar){...}
```

I can pass it a map without needing the '&'.

```
myFunc(someMapitoa);
```

Is there any difference? Is a copy made and then thrown away? Should I use the '&' anyway?

Comment: No a copy is not made. It is passed by reference. Using '&' when calling myFunc would take the address of the field and cause a compile error.

Comment: What is "implied"? You explicitly state that the parameter is by reference.

Comment: The `&` in the function declaration indicates that the variable in question is a [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference_initialization), whereas the `&` elsewhere is the [`address-of` operator](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB0QFjAAahUKEwjIka2Zr-PIAhUGaD4KHbWjCts&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2F64sa8b1e.aspx&usg=AFQjCNHtYjVhhfSqTvIOqKLfmC_VV7hAhw). Don't conflate the two.

Comment: @NeilKirk One can see it as 'implied' at the call site. But, I agree. In C++ it's explicit with the function definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should think of this in terms of what is being initialized from what.

When you call a function, each argument is used to initialize the corresponding parameter. If the parameter is declared with reference type, it's a reference. If the parameter is not declared with reference type, it's an object.

- The initialization of a **reference** to class type `T` from an expression of type `T` **never makes a copy.**
- The initialization of an **object** of class type `T` from an expression of type `T` **either copies or moves.**

The rules here are the same as the rules for initializing non-parameter variables, as in:

```
T t = ...
T& r = ...
```

The fact that a function may take a reference to an argument even when there is no explicit notation at the call site is viewed by some as confusing. This is why some style guides ban non-`const` reference parameters (such as the Google C++ style guide) and force you to declare the argument as a *pointer* so that `&` must be used at the call site. I don't advocate this coding style, but it is an option you might want to consider.

Answer (score 5):

C++ is pass-by-value by default.

So, this makes a copy:

```
void foo (bar b);
```

This does not:

```
void foo (bar & b);
```

This makes a copy of a pointer, but not the actual data that it points to:

```
void foo (bar * b);
```

If you really want to get deeper into it then see [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106110/what-are-move-semantics) about move semantics.

Anyway, for the above three examples they are all called the same way:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int alpha (int arg) {
    // we can do anything with arg and it won't impact my caller
    // because arg is just a copy of what my caller passed me
    arg = arg + 1;
    return arg;
}

int bravo (int & arg) {
    // if I do anything to arg it'll change the value that my caller passed in
    arg = arg + 1;
    return arg;
}

int charlie (int * arg) {
    // when we deal with it like this it's pretty much the same thing
    // as a reference even though it's not exactly the same thing
    *arg = *arg + 1;
    return *arg;
}

int main () {
    int a = 0;

    // 1
    cout << alpha (a) << endl;
    // 1
    cout << bravo (a) << endl;
    // 2
    cout << charlie (&a) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```